# Where's sshd in OpenSuse 13.2?

Tags: ssh, opensuse, chkconfig

After I installed OpenSuse 13.2 I discovered that even if the ssh connection to the box were successful I could not find the running service as I did before (with **chkconfig** command)

Why?

My last familiar Suse release was 11.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old init system has been replaced by SystemD, with `systemctl` as the main interface to that system.

Comment: Can you tell under what name is now (open)ssh daemon hidden? (before was sshd)

Comment: No, I don't really use SuSE and have no system with it available. You can check yourself with `systemctl list-units`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 systemctl list-units sshd.service
```

(actual service found by using `systemctl list-units | grep ssh` , no need for root by the way)

```
Archemar@tatouin:~/> systemctl list-units sshd.service
UNIT         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
sshd.service loaded active running OpenSSH Daemon

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```